# Meaning of WHERE in correlated subquery

Tags: sql, where-clause, correlated-subquery

```
SELECT odate, SUM (amt)
FROM Orders a
GROUP BY odate
HAVING SUM (amt) > ( SELECT 2000.00 + MAX (amt)
                     FROM Orders b
                     WHERE a.odate = b.odate );
```

The subquery without `WHERE` itself returns `MAX(amt)`, its a single value - *9891.88 in this case*, how can we apply `WHERE` on a single value?

[image: Orders table]

Comment: Its an example of query from SQL book

Answer (score 0):

This is a coorrelated subquery.

A correlated subquery is a subquery that depends on the outer query. It means that the WHERE clause of the correlated subquery uses the data of the outer query.

So subquery will only have those dates which are common in both the table

Comment: ```SELECT odate, SUM (amt)
FROM Orders a
GROUP BY odate
HAVING SUM (amt) > ( SELECT 2000.00 + MAX (amt) FROM Orders)```
This wont work?